# How to deal with database password on fatcow server using pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, pdo, passwords

Well, I'd like to understand why when I set a password to the database, all connections are lost. For example, if I set the password to 123, I can't have access to database and an error message is shown, kind of like:

`Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'10.1.112.103' (using password: NO)`

Of course, whenever I change a password for accessing phpmyadmin embedded on Fatcow server, I also want to make sure I changed this info in the config.php too.

When I set no password (password = "";), all connections work normally.

This works:

config.php

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database','root','');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Now, this does NOT work:

config.php

```
<?php
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database','root','123');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Having in mind that I'm using PDO (I'm not using MySQLi), my PHP version is 5.5.32 and the server is of Fatcow, why is this happening and how to solve this little problem so that I can use a password to protect my database? In my php.ini file,
`mysql.default_password =`. I don't know if the problem is there or in the .htaccess Editor.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking why adding a password makes logging in without that password not work. That question answers itself, so can you [edit] to clarify what you're really getting at?

Comment: Your `.htaccess` file has nothing to do with it. Also, there's no need to touch the `mysql.default_password`. How are you changing your MySQL user's password? All you need to do is login to mysql `mysql -uroot`, then, change the password for the root user properly. `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123');`. Change `123` accordingly.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy, no, you didn't understand. Of course your premise is totally correct, cause it would be dumb of me asking such an obvious question. In fact what I wanna understand is why connections are lost, when I set any password to my database in my own hosting account settings for MySQL database within FatCow server.

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares: I *know* I didn't understand. That was my point: that your question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, whenever I set a password for the database username (root), connections are lost. If I set no password, everything works perfectly, in as much as I change this password in the config.php file shown above, of course! The password is not set manually in SQL, but in a form within the program embedded in FatCow (PHPMyAdmin, that I regard as a little old in Fatcow).

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Actually you are not setting a password.You  try to connect a database with a password and your database has no password..So passwords don't match

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, if I'm not mistaken, they run version 5. I really don't know if it's 5.something...

Comment: No, @Eren Ardahan. You don't get the point. The passwords match perfectly, even when I set the password to "ballcat" for example.

Comment: I understand, but 5.1, 5.5, 5.6.5?

Comment: I actually don't know.

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares So i assume that you change the password with phpmyadmin..And also did you changed the config.php or config.inc.php there must be a config file?You need to add a line there

Comment: @ErenArdahan, both in phpmyadmin and in config.php the password has been changed. Simple as that. When I set the password to none (password = '') using both ways, all works perfectly. The problem is when I set any password using both ways. The config.php file does not work, because there is a connection error and an error message is shown like explained above. This nor do I even get to understand, if at all you understand me... Again, If I set the password to 1, connection failed, password set to none, all successful...

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares try to add this line in your config php---->$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123'; and copy paste your try catch into your root with openning and closing php tag in a php file..

Comment: @ErenArdahan, okay but where exactly do I put it?

Comment: if there is a www root create a connectiontest.php file and put it  there.As I mentioned that is not for set a password..That's for testing a connection...

Comment: Sorry, this is being a bit hard to picture in mind. Could u demonstrate this?